# Add Note Button to Repeating Table

Tags: repeating-table

Is there a way to have a button where on pressed takes the 'Value' from a repeating table, appends to 'History Value' with time/date stamp while the form is still opened? 
I've tried having buttons refresh / update / submit / switch views and nothing I've tried has been effective. The only way it's properly working is upon Save / Close / Reopen record.

Repeating tables have prebuilt functions such as remove record and insert above etc.